# fabric.js - Cloned path groups not rendering from JSON

Tags: json, svg, fabricjs

I am loading a SVG, converting to a path group, cloning several times and then saving to JSON. On restoring from JSON, the path groups don't appear on the canvas, although the fabric objects are there (bounding boxes show on selection), but the path groups have arrays of [0]. Any idea why this has happened? In the gif below I'm using an undo/redo method, I undo and when I redo the path groups are gone but the fabric objects are still there. Please note: I have posted the key code below, I can't post my full source code. I hope someone can figure out what's happening here based on the info provided.

[image]

```
// Load SVG and convert to path group.
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(objects, options){
   group = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   canvas.add(group);
   canvas.renderAll();
}); 

// Clone group and add to canvas
group.clone(function(c: any) {
    c.add(group);
});

// Save canvas to JSON
var obj = canvas.toJSON();

// Clear canvas and load JSON
canvas.clear();
canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(obj);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `canvas.toJSON();`

`JSON.stringify(canvas);` works fine.